# Sources of Mutations

Tags: cancer, mutations

I'm looking for a reference that gives some information quantifying sources of mutations that occur within cells. These can be general, but I'm interested in some percentage of mutations caused by external vs internal sources (like mutagens vs replication errors).

Comment: This is going to strongly depend on the cell type, where it's located in the body, the type of organism, etc. Are you interested in looking at cancer, which occurs in pretty much all cell types, or heredity, in which the mutations must occur in the germ cells, or what?

Comment: There is an issue of epistemology when talking about the "sources of mutations". The question makes little sense and you should rather be asking about the "factors causing variation in mutation rates".

Comment: See this: http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nature12477

Answer (score 1):

An extensive collection of the various mutation rates (from which you could reverse-engineer their fraction on the total share of mutations):

http://www.bionumbers.hms.harvard.edu/search.aspx?log=y&task=searchbytrmorg&trm=mutations&org=&rpp=100

Comment: cool site I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found this in the following paper:

http://science.sciencemag.org/content/348/6237/880.full

This group shows estimated governing forces in mutation incidence by tissue types.